# Execute multiple blocks concurrently in a dispatch barrier

Tags: ios, concurrency, queue, grand-central-dispatch, barrier

I want to send 2 types of requests to a web service. The first is a POST which changes the backend state. The second is a GET which retrieves data from the backend. I want to be able to have multiple POST requests sent concurrently since they won't cause desynchronization. But, I want a GET request to be sent serially in association with the POST requests (when the GET requests is sent, no POST requests can be sent while the GET response is not received. I implemented this with a dispatch barrier for the GET request.

My problem is that while one GET request is being executed, I want the option for more GET requests to be sent concurrently as well and the barrier to break when the last sent GET request's response is received.

I've been trying to make this work using dispatch barriers but haven't found a solution so far. Maybe the solution should be looked for elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GCD barrier approach, there are two things to be sensitive to:

1. Your dispatched tasks should not complete until the network request is done (otherwise you're synchronizing the issuing of requests, but not the whole request-through-response process).
2. You will need to have *three* types of tasks that can be dispatched: GETs (with no barrier), POSTs (with no barrier), and some "switch" task (with barrier) that you use whenever you're switching from GETs to POSTs. This "switch" task doesn't need to do anything, but is just there so you have a barrier.

   So, keep track of whether last request was a GET or a POST, e.g. `lastRequestType`, and if the new task is not of the same type, then first dispatch your "switch" barrier task before dispatching the new network request task.

   Obviously, this whole process of "check `lastRequestType`, issue 'switch' barrier and update last request type if necessary, and issue  new request" will need to be synchronized in order to make it thread safe.

There are other approaches, too. For example, you can use operation queues (perhaps one for most recent GETs, one for most recent POSTs), and use dependencies to ensure that POSTs wait for the prior GETs and vice versa. Likewise you'll need this "last request type was GET or POST" variable in order to know whether you need to add dependencies or not (and, again, this all needs to be properly synchronized). This approach lets you:

- lets you wrap asynchronous network requests in `NSOperation` subclass, thereby avoiding ugliness of point 1 above; and
- allows you to control the degree of concurrency, something I always like to do when dealing with large number of network requests (particularly if they could be slow).

---

If you forgive me for saying this, but while both of the above approaches work, the whole idea feels over-engineered. I'd suggest you push really hard and challenge the premise that GETs and POSTs cannot happen concurrently. That decision feels a bit arbitrary, like some engineer was spitballing, looking for a easy solution, and suggested that GETs and POSTs shouldn't happen concurrently. I'd spend a little time figuring out what the alternative would look like before going too far in your implementation of the above. Lots of us write apps with concurrent GETs and POSTs, but without this complexity.

For example, if I had a series of POST requests that I wanted to perform and wanted to issue a final GET request when they were done, I might recommend a `DispatchGroup`, where the individual posts are dispatched using the group, and then you can be notified when you want to do the final GET:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

networkQueue.async(group: group) {
    // POST 1
}

networkQueue.async(group: group) {
    // POST 2
}

group.notify(queue: networkQueue) {
    // final GET
}
```

Or, if you're using simple asynchronous methods (without semaphores, thereby avoiding blocking threads unnecessarily), you can still use dispatch groups:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
performFirstPost {
    // POST 1 finished
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
performSecondPost {
    // POST 2 finished
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: networkQueue) {
    // final GET
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, here are my explanations:

1. Why I need this synchronization? The situation is roughly as follows: The GET request retrieves a list of items from the backend. The POST request flags an item of that list (like marking it as a favorite). If you send a POST request and before you get the response, you send a GET request, there's no guarantee that the order of how those requests are going to be received by the backend and the order in which the responses will be received by the app.

Comment: The worst case is: 1. POST request, 2. GET request, 3. GET request received on backend, 4. POST request received on backend, 5. GET response received in the app, 6. POST response received in the app. In this case what will happen is: the user will try to mark an item as a favorite, request a refresh afterwards, get a feedback that the item was marked as favorite and then get a refreshed list where that item is not marked as favorite while the same item is actually marked as favorite on the backend.

Comment: 2. I use semaphores to make the request-response process a one blocking process.
3. The idea with a switch barrier task is a very interesting one. Unfortunately it doesn't handle one other special case. Each GET request-response can take different times to execute. What I want is to just wait on the latest one and disregard the ones that were done before the latest one. By using barriers of any kind, I still have to wait for the old GET request (which might take longer than the new one) to finish before other POST requests can be sent again.

Comment: Re the semaphore to make it behave synchronously, that's great. It's amazing how often I see questions on S.O. where they don't do that, and they wonder why it didn't wait for the response. On the bigger question, my question is why don't you do the GET request in the completion handler of the POST request. Then you don't have to worry about it. Or, even better, if you have control over the web service API, have the POST response (optionally, if you want) return what you'd want from the subsequent GET request, then you eliminate an entire request and improve performance and solve the problem.

Comment: Sending the GET request in the completion handler of the POST request won't be feasible since "I want to be able to have multiple POST requests sent concurrently". So the GET request should be sent after ALL the other POST request-responses are done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160330/discussion-between-jovan-jovanovski-and-rob).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of thought and a lot of help from @Rob which I'm very grateful for, the result is that it's best not to use GCD and use OperationQueue instead. 
[This is a gist with a playground of the implementation along with the tests.](https://gist.github.com/yoshimkd/cd9961f3149b6a3177ad25589d714f0e) 
This is its code:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

import Foundation

final class OperationsManager {

    private let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")

    private let nonexclusiveOperationsQueue = OperationQueue()
    private let exclusiveOperationQueue = OperationQueue()

    func add(operation: Operation, exclusive: Bool) {
        serialQueue.async {
            if exclusive {
                self.exclusiveOperationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
                print("Ignore the finish of the previous exclusive operation")

                self.nonexclusiveOperationsQueue.operations.forEach {
                    nonexclusiveOperation in
                    operation.addDependency(nonexclusiveOperation)
                }
                self.exclusiveOperationQueue.addOperation(operation)
            } else {
                self.exclusiveOperationQueue.operations.forEach {
                    exclusiveOperation in
                    operation.addDependency(exclusiveOperation)
                }
                self.nonexclusiveOperationsQueue.addOperation(operation)
            }
        }
    }

}

final class BlockedAsynchronousOperation: Operation {

    private var semaphore: DispatchSemaphore?
    private let block: (@escaping () -> ()) -> ()

    init(block: @escaping (@escaping () -> ()) -> ()) {
        self.block = block
    }

    override func cancel() {
        super.cancel()
        semaphore?.signal()
    }

    override func main() {
        super.main()

        semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        block {
            [weak self] in
            self?.semaphore?.signal()
        }
        semaphore!.wait()
    }

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
func longRunningOperation(
    seconds: Int, completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(
        deadline: .now() + .seconds(seconds),
        execute: completionHandler)
}

func blockedAsynchronousOperation(
    withID id: String, seconds: Int) -> BlockedAsynchronousOperation {
    return BlockedAsynchronousOperation {
        unblockHandler in
        print("Operation with ID: \(id) started")
        longRunningOperation(seconds: seconds) {
            unblockHandler()
            print("Operation with ID: \(id) finished")
        }
    }
}

func addOperation(
    withID id: Int,
    exclusive: Bool,
    atSeconds startSeconds: Int,
    duration: Int,
    inOperationsManager operationsManager: OperationsManager) {
    let block = {
        operationsManager.add(operation:
            blockedAsynchronousOperation(
                withID: (exclusive ? "GET " : "POST ") +
                    String(id), seconds: duration), exclusive: exclusive)
    }
    if startSeconds > 0 {
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(
            deadline: .now() + .seconds(startSeconds), execute: block)
    } else {
        block()
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
print("global start\n")

let operationsManager = OperationsManager()

addOperation(
    withID: 1,
    exclusive: false,
    atSeconds: 0,
    duration: 7,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 2,
    exclusive: false,
    atSeconds: 0,
    duration: 5,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 1,
    exclusive: true,
    atSeconds: 0,
    duration: 10,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 2,
    exclusive: true,
    atSeconds: 3,
    duration: 10,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 3,
    exclusive: true,
    atSeconds: 10,
    duration: 10,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 3,
    exclusive: false,
    atSeconds: 15,
    duration: 5,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 4,
    exclusive: false,
    atSeconds: 16,
    duration: 5,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 4,
    exclusive: true,
    atSeconds: 28,
    duration: 10,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 5,
    exclusive: true,
    atSeconds: 31,
    duration: 20,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)
addOperation(
    withID: 6,
    exclusive: true,
    atSeconds: 34,
    duration: 2,
    inOperationsManager: operationsManager)

print("\nglobal end\n")

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: A few minor observations: 1. In `add`, you can `serialQueue.async` instead of `sync`. 2. Your `BlockedAsynchronousOperation` is obviously not an asynchronous operation. It's a synchronous operation. (Whether an operation is `asynchronous` or not is defined by whether it returns from `main` before the operation is completed or not.) It's not material here, but it just suggests a misunderstanding of what asynchronous operations are. I also want to make sure you excise semaphores from your network code if you go `Operation` route. But with those minor observations, this should do what you need.

Comment: My considerations:
1. The access is sync with the purpose to lock the process of adding exclusive operations, otherwise the exclusive operations queue may end up with more than one operation at a time.
2. In my specific implementation the part that connect to the network is abstracted out (it's just a request to a resource that returns a value after some time) - that's why I didn't want to include the network code. My idea was to make the BlockedAsynchronousOperation a general way to schedule a process that is asynchronous itself and make it synchronous easily.

Comment: 1. If it’s a serial queue, and if everything you do with the synchronized object is on that queue, there’s no reasoning to wait for it. E.g. in reader-writer pattern, reads are done synchronously (because you have to wait for the value), but writes can done with a barrier _asynchronously._ 2. OK, but it’s just weird to create an example called `BlockedAsynchronousOperation` that is not an asynchronous operation. (Do you get my point, that an “asynchronous” operation has very specific meaning that has nothing to do with the fact it’s async with respect to main thread, but rather re `main`?)

Comment: ... A better example of a `BlockedAsynchronousOperation` demo might be an operation that wraps something like a GCD timer (where you schedule the timer, `main`/`start` then returns, and you don't change the state of the operation to `finished` until the timer fires or the op is canceled). See [Asynchronous vs Synchronous Operations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation#1661231). By the way, please forgive the fairly minor observations: But you did ask me for my thoughts. ;)

Comment: @Rob, thank you very much for your thoughts, the solution wouldn't have even existed it it weren't for your thoughts :)